# Session Timeout after specific time with AlertDialog

Tags: android

Before referring me to other threads on this forum and marking my question as duplicate kindly read my question. I have to create a global application timeout. No matter which activity is user on, after specific amount of time the user will be displayed AlertDialog that his session has expired and he can exit or renew his session. I have read different solutions and used service as my solution.

```
public class InActivityTimer extends Service {

MyCounter timer;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    timer = new MyCounter(20 * 1000,1000);
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    timer.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("timeout_action");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        // Need AlertDialog code here

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Time Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished/1000)+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

The problem is that I can display the Toast without any problem but the AlertDialog is not displayed when called inside onFinish().

The first problem is to display the AlertDialog for whole application bearing in mind that the AlertDialog is displayed for some context. Also if somehow the AlertDialog is displayed then how to close the Application. On Activity I just close the activity by calling finish() so should I clear the Activities stack in this case?

The second complex part that I am facing is to display a popup when user click "Time remaining" link in the application which will show how much time is remaining for the Session to be timed out. This time should be exactly same as the time remaining in the service.

I can also use BroadcastReceiver and send update to the activity once the time is finished but wouldn't that be Activity specific because I want the timeout to act same regardless of which activity is user on. I want to avoid writing the same code on each activity.

Kindly guide me through with some solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're aware that `AlertDialog` needs a `Context` in order to work. However, more specifically, `AlertDialog` needs an `Activity`, or a window, to attach to in order for it to display. You will likely get a crash if you attempt to show an `AlertDialog` if you pass it the `Context` from your `Service` telling you about some invalid window token (or something similar). Perhaps you could register a broadcast receiver in an `Activity` and dispatch the `AlertDialog` from in there. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I could use the Broadcast receiver but wouldn't that be activity specific. Can it work same for all activities? Means the alerts and time will be same for all activities? Overall is it a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with rather very simple approach.

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TimeoutActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);        

    stopSelf();
}
```

and below is the onCreate method for my TimeoutActivity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(TimeoutDialogActivity.this, R.style.Theme_Base_AppCompat_Dialog_FixedSize);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw).create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Session Timeout !");
    alertDialog.setTitle("Your session has expired.");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Logout", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            alertDialog.dismiss();
finish();   
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Renew Session", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                alertDialog.dismiss();
                finish();

    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a fragment based design for your app, you can keep a root FragmentActivity in which all other elements of the app are displayed. This way you can use the context of the root FragmentActivity every time, to display your Dialog.

---

Additional: "Could you kindly refer to me some article.."

What you are doing is not common, and I would have to google search just like you to find any existing example similar to your case. I can however fill in a bit more detail on what I have proposed above.

If you are unfamiliar with using Fragments, read the [Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH_SCREEN_FRAGMENT = 0;
    private static final int HOME_SCREEN_FRAGMENT = 1;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle. savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // show your first fragment
        Fragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, splashFragment).commit();

        // Start your service using the context of your FragmentActivity
        // Your FragmentActivity will always be the current activity, and you will display
        // all other elements of your app inside it as fragments
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, InActivityTimer.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    // method for switching the displayed fragment
    private void fragmentSwitcher(int fragmentType) {

        Fragment currentFragment = new Fragment();

        switch (currentFragmentType) {
            case SPLASH_SCREEN_FRAGMENT:
                currentFragment = new SplashScreenFragment();
                break;
            case HOME_SCREEN_FRAGMENT:
                currentFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
                break;
            ...
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, currentFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly refer to me some article from which I could get the idea to write this code as seeing is believing and will be more helpful for me.